# How does substitution rule in calculus work?

Tags: calculus

How does this substitution rule in calculus work?
$$\int\limits^ {}_{}  {\frac{\ln^{2}y}{5y+6y\ln^{3}y}} \, dy$$
How can we use the substitution rule here to get $u = \ln^3 y$
and $du = \frac{3\ln^2 y}{y} dy$
so how do we get from the first equation to:
$$\int \frac{1}{3(5+6u)} \, du$$

Where does $1$ in numerator and $3$ in denominator come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just:

$$\frac{\ln^{2}y}{5y+6y\ln^{3}y}=\frac{1}{5+6\ln^3y}\cdot\frac{\ln^2y}{y}$$

Then :

$$
\begin{align} 
\frac{\ln^{2}y}{5y+6y\ln^{3}y}\,dy&=\frac{1}{5+6\ln^3y}\cdot\frac{\ln^2y}{y}\,dy\\
&=\frac{1}{5+6u}\cdot\frac{du}3
\end{align} 
$$

Comment: Thank you, I can understand up until the very last 3 in the denominator. Where does that come from?

Comment: You say $du=3\frac{\ln^2y}{y}\,dy.$ So $$\frac{du}{3}=\frac{\ln^2y}{y}\,dy.$$

Comment: oh wow, im not sure how i didnt understand that at first. thank you greatly...

Answer (score 0):

Notice that by factoring out the $y$ in the denominator, $$\displaystyle{\frac{\ln^{2}y}{5y+6y\ln^{3}y}}
=\frac{1}{\color{green}{3\cdot \frac{1}{3}}(5+6\ln^3y)} \frac{\ln^2y}{y}
=\frac{1}{\color{green}{3}(5+6\ln^3y)} \frac{\color{green}{3}\ln^2y}{y}
$$
and thus
$$
\int{\frac{\ln^{2}y}{5y+6y\ln^{3}y}}  dy
=\int \frac{1}{3(5+6\color{red}{\ln^3y})} \color{blue}{\frac{3\ln^2y}{y}\ dy}
$$
Then it is quite straightforward to see how the substitution works.

---

Notes: The *expression* you refer to is an (indefinite) integral, not an "equation". In mathematics, an [equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation) is a statement that asserts the equality of two expressions, which are connected by the equals sign "=".

Comment: okay, i see up until the point that 3 is outside the parentheses. where does that 3 derive from? thank you

Comment: @stapmoshun: simple: $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{a}{3}\cdot 3b$.

Comment: @stapmoshun: please, see the edit.